# Highcharts synchronized charts showing multiple times

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts

I am trying to create 2 synchronized charts. Here are the the sample code available:

- [highchart demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/synchronized-charts)
- [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/synchronized-charts/)

The problem is that I need to update the 2 synchronized charts each time the user presses a certain link in a map. So the code that I mentioned above I call inside this block

```
$(document).on("submit", "#someform", function(event) {
    var $form = $(this);
    console.log("submit done");
    $.post($form.attr("action"), $form.serialize(), function(response) { 
        // here read the data
        // then here call the function mentioned above from Highcharts site
```

The problem is that each time I click the link two new charts are created, so, I end up after 4 clicks with 8 charts instead of having only 2. I suspect the problem is with this line from the original code:

```
$('<div class="chart">')
    .appendTo('#container')
    .highcharts({...`
```

which adds new div's elements each time. What can be done to correct this? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime you click "submit", a new chart will be added in the `div`. So a simple solution is removing the old chart in the `div` and adding a new one, using [`.empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/):

```
$.post($form.attr("action"), $form.serialize(), function(response) { 
  // remove the old chart
  $('<div class="chart">').empty();
  // add the new chart
  $('<div class="chart">').appendTo('#container').highcharts({...
  });
};
```

Comment: This is a good ideea! It did not work with `$('<div class="chart">').empty();` but seems to work with `$(".chart").empty();`  But now appears another problem, the crosshairs are broken, not correlated anymore and in the browser's console there is this error: **(index):185 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pointer' of undefined** at this line `      event = chart.pointer.normalize(e.originalEvent); // Find coordinates within the chart`

Comment: @Sorin try to empty the `$('#container')`, but not `$(".chart")`.

Comment: I found the problem, beside the synchronized charts I had  in the page other 2 charts and when executing that line of code, it tried to iterate through all charts, even in the non-synchronized ones. So, fixed this. Thank you

Comment: @Sorin you're welcome, so could you accepter my answer?

Comment: I tried to vote for it but seems I do not have enough reputation to vote.

Comment: @Sorin Accepting the answer don't need any reputation(but voting need). And by accepting the answer, you can gain your reputation, so that in the future you can vote.

Comment: @Sorin have u seen a tick just below the down flech?

Comment: i did not know about it, i am relatively new to this site. pressed it now.

Comment: @Sorin Thx, you could get more familiar to the site from now on.